# Extracting nested JSON values in Spark Streaming Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

How should I parse json messages from Kafka in Spark Streaming?
I'm converting JavaRDD to Dataset and from there extracting the values. Found success in extracting values however I'm not able to extract nested json values such as "host.name" and "fields.type".

Incoming message from Kafka:

```
{
  "@timestamp": "2020-03-03T10:48:03.160Z",
  "@metadata": {
    "beat": "filebeat",
    "type": "_doc",
    "version": "7.6.0"
  },
  "host": {
    "name": "test.com"
  },
  "agent": {
    "id": "7651453414",
    "version": "7.6.0",
    "type": "filebeat",
    "ephemeral_id": "71983698531",
    "hostname": "test"
  },
  "message": "testing",
  "log": {
    "file": {
      "path": "/test.log"
    },
    "offset": 250553
  },
  "input": {
    "type": "log"
  },
  "fields": {
    "type": "test"
  },
  "ecs": {
    "version": "1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Spark code :

```
StructField[] structFields = new StructField[] {
            new StructField("message", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()) };
StructType structType = new StructType(structFields);

StructField[] structFields2 = new StructField[] {
            new StructField("host", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("fields", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("message", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()) };
StructType structType2 = new StructType(structFields2);

JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rdd.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, Row>() {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -8817714250698168398L;

        @Override
        public Row call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> r) {
            Row row = RowFactory.create(r.value());
            return row;
        }
    });
    Dataset<Row> rowExtracted = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD.rdd(), structType)
            .select(functions.from_json(functions.col("message"), structType2).as("data")).select("data.*");
    rowExtracted.printSchema();
    rowExtracted.show((int) rowExtracted.count(), false);
```

PrintSchema :

```
root
 |-- host: string (nullable = true)
 |-- fields: string (nullable = true)
 |-- message: string (nullable = true)
```

Actual Output :

```
+---------------+---------------+-------+
|host           |fields         |message|
+---------------+---------------+-------+
|{"name":"test"}|{"type":"test"}|testing|
+---------------+---------------+-------+
```

Expected Output :

```
+---------------+---------------+-------+
|host           |fields         |message|
+---------------+---------------+-------+
|test           |test           |testing|
+---------------+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
StructField[] structFieldsName = new StructField[] {
            new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
            };
StructType structTypeName = new StructType(structFieldsName);


StructField[] structFieldsType = new StructField[] {
            new StructField("type", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
            };
StructType structTypeNested = new StructType(structFieldsType);

StructField[] structFieldsMsg = new StructField[] {
            new StructField("host", structTypeName , true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("fields", structTypeNested, true, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField("message", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty())
            };
StructType structTypeMsg = new StructType(structFieldsMsg);

Dataset<Row> rowExtracted = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD.rdd(), structTypeMsg)
```